# visual studio: calloc redefinition

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to compile some code for which i have to compile meschach library and some other library which has codes for malloc, calloc etc.

I run into a problem where my visual studio 2010 express compiler complains

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdlib.h(598): error C2375: 'calloc' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\work\malloc\malloc.h(98) : see declaration of 'calloc'
```

Comment: What is `c:\work\malloc\malloc.h`, where did that file come from, and why is it redefining a standard function?

Comment: malloc shouldn't be used directly in c++. my guess is you are trying to compile some C files in a c++ project.

Comment: the malloc.h came with the library that i am trying to compile. it has a bunch of other ones like calloc, realloc etc. is there a way to bypass the standard function and reuse these ?

Comment: @Ionut. yes you are correct. The library is in c. and i am trying to compile it in visual studio 2010 express.

Comment: well you can't just add .c files to your c++ project. they use different compilers.

Comment: Um. yeah you can. unless changed from the default VC++ will run cl.exe in c-compile mode on all .c files, just like it runs the assembler across all .asm files.

Comment: If you want to use a replacement for the standard C library, you have to avoid including anything from the standard C library—and, once you get past that, you'll also have to tell the linker to skip the standard C library. But my guess is that the real problem here is that, whatever library you're actually trying to use (maybe you should tell us which one?) hasn't been configured right.

Comment: I believe this part is the most important `redefinition; different linkage`. It means the linker has noticed that there are two *different* functions, one of which doesn't exactly match the prototype in the included header.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if `c:\work\malloc\malloc.h` is a project where you're basically writing `calloc`? If that is the case, then you need to either not include `stdlib.h` or call your version of `calloc` something different.

Comment: I have seen somewhere that it is possible to `UNDEF` a standard library symbol (e.g. `calloc()`) and give a new definition of it.